# How to convert XML SOAP String to JSONObject (com.ibm.json.java.JSONObject)

Tags: json, xml

Good Day,

I have created a java class in Adapter IBM Mobilefirst Platform that will get response from the Jax-ws service.

```
     // read direct to soap service - 4/4/2017
        protected JSONObject createJsonObjectFrmSOAPRequest(Map mapsData) throws IOException, SOAPException {
            JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
            String responseSoap="";
            // Create SOAP Connection
            SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
            SOAPConnection soapConnection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();
            try {
            // Send SOAP Message to SOAP Server
            String url = "http://XXXXX:001/test-pvr-ws/empl_get";
            SOAPMessage soapResponse = soapConnection.call(createSOAPRequest(mapsData), url);

            // Process the SOAP Response
            responseSoap = printSOAPResponse(soapResponse);

            // how to convert to jsonobject, the output is in xml string
            //  XMLToJSONTransformer.transform(responseSoap); - don't know how to use XMLToJSONTransformer
            //JSONObject.parse(responseSoap); // convert String to JSONObject


            logger.info("jsonObject : " + jsonObj);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return jsonObj;
        }


        protected String printSOAPResponse(SOAPMessage soapResponse) throws Exception {
            String finalstringEnv = "";

            try {

                TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                Source sourceContent = soapResponse.getSOAPPart().getContent();
                System.out.print("\nResponse SOAP Message = ");
                //create a StringWriter for the output
                StringWriter outWriter = new StringWriter();
             // StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out); // this is for print line output
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(outWriter);
                transformer.transform(sourceContent, result);
             // how to convert Transformer.transform() to String java
                StringBuffer sb = outWriter.getBuffer(); 
                finalstringEnv = sb.toString();


            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



        return finalstringEnv;
        }
```

2 . This code will get the Response in XML string, but I don't know how to use library com.ibm.json.*. Which I wanted to convert the String Response to JSONObject.

2.1. Result Response in XML Soap Envelope (example successful Result i got).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
    <a:getTheResponse xmlns:a="http://XXXXX:001/test-pvr-ws/empl_get/">
    <getTheRecord>
    <statusCode>0</statusCode>
    <getTheRecord>
    <userid>1212</userid>
    </a:getTheResponse>
    </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

2.2. responseSoap String variable i need to convert String XML Soap response To  JSONObject

```
    // Process the SOAP Response
      responseSoap = printSOAPResponse(soapResponse);
    //.............. code to convert String XML Soap response To  JSONObject
```

Comment: if I may, what requires the conversion to `JSON`?  Isn't the `XML` richer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my Question:

Recently I just trying , I need to use this method XMLToJSONTransformer (com.ibm.json.xml.XMLToJSONTransformer) to convert the XML string to JSONObject.

```
String jsonObjectStr ="";

// convert String to JSONObject
jsonObjectStr = xmlToJsonTransformer.transform(responseSoap);
        jsonObj = JSONObject.parse(jsonObjectStr);
```